# Run cakephp app in apache alias

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, alias, virtualhost

I'm trying to deploy a cakephp 3.1 app in a apache 2.4 powered server. My boss would like to place the app in a directory different of server's documentroot (`DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"` in my httpd.conf file), since multiple webapps will be served by this server.

Instead of virtualhosts, he would like to use aliases (host/app1, host/app2 etc). So I'm trying to configure it this way. I put an alias to my cake app (`Alias "/scqa" "/opt/scqa/webroot"` in my httpd.conf file) and wrote a RewriteBase (`RewriteBase /scqa`) to both cake's .htaccess files, but every absolute link present in my app is still pointing to apache's documentroot. In this particular case, it means my css and a big pile of not properly built links are 404ing. Is there some way I can fix it in apache configuration? 
I know 2 other ways to fix it: Fix the links with cake syntax (will take me a week) or use virtualhosts. But is it possible to fix it and keep using apache alias?

Thanks in advance.

(The production env uses centos 7 64bits, just in case)

Comment: My boss was finnally convinced to use a virtualhost. Cake's documentation explicitly says it should be the documentroot of the server (or vhost), but I still don't know if a workaround can be made.

Comment: Bruno, I ran into a similar problem that I eventually found and fixed.  But my problem was that I hadn't added the RewriteBase to my .htaccess files (which you had).  Nonetheless my answer has all the semantics detailed with code snippets from when I finally got it working.  You can look at my answer to verify your semantics here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39352928/883354

Answer (score -1):

If I understood well, you are using aliases in your .htaccess files. 
You should put the `Alias` in your server config file, because it won't work otherwise.

Syntax: Alias [URL-path] file-path|directory-path

Context:    **server config, virtual host, directory**

From https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: Sorry if I gave that impression. The alias and the documentroot are setted in my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. The rewritebase is written in my .htaccess files. =D