# Using an alias in my Apache's httpd.conf to point to a cakephp 3.0 directory results in error 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp-3.0, httpd.conf

On my CentOS LAMP.  I have a website, www.mydomain.com.  In my httpd.conf I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@myemail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cakephp
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    <Directory /var/www/cakephp/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So www.mydomain.com is served from /var/www/cakephp.

But I want it so that URL "www.mydomain.com/powercontroller/" is served from: /var/www/powercontroller.  So I put this alias into httpd.conf as well:

```
Alias /powercontroller/ "/var/www/powercontroller/"
<Directory "/var/www/powercontroller/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

But it doesn't work.  The URL "www.mydomian.com/powercontroller" in my browser gives me error 404 "The requested URL /var/www/powercontroller/webroot/ was not found on this server."

My /var/www/powercontroller directory has the following:

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

index.php

```
require 'webroot' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'index.php';
```

These are the default files from Cakephp 3.0 setup.  And there is certainly a webroot directory with everything in place from the default Cakephp 3.0.

I know I must be partway there because at least it's looking in the powercontroller directory.  But for some reason it insists it cannot find the webroot.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason not to make the directories in the `httpd.conf` point at the webroot folders directly? I think that's the more typical setup. But that doesn't explain why it thinks that `/var/www` is part of your resulting URL. Any chance there's something else in your config or an `.htaccess` file somewhere, perhaps a leftover from earlier tests, that's causing this?

Comment: This is how I've always been doing it, making the document root or the alias point to the directory you get from the cakephp 3.0 composer thing.  That directory has the .htaccess and index.php pointing to the webroot.  I'll add them to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out.  When you alias to a cakephp 3.0 app directory then your .htaccess in both your app directory and your webroot directory needs a RewriteBase directive.  So in my case file /var/www/powercontroller/.htaccess and file /var/www/powercontroller/webroot/.htaccess both need the line:

```
RewriteBase /powercontroller/
```

right below their line

```
RewriteEngine on
```

This information is found almost nowhere.  [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35701544/883354) a similar question that was never answered correctly, that I'll now answer.  And [here's](https://askubuntu.com/a/490885/38180) an analogous answer about drupal that was the only clue I found in a week of searching.